# Finding name of inserted CD in Cocoa

Tags: cocoa, xcode, macos, mount, cd

I had a bookmark which described the process on how to do this - finding the name of a mounted CD in OS X - but I deleted the bookmark when I reformatted my Mac. :P

Reading up on the subject, this is what I think might work.  Basically, I need to verify if a particular CD is mounted before continuing in the application

1. Access NSWorkspace
2. Perform 'checkForRemovableMedia'
3. Grab array of mounted media paths from 'mountedRemoveableMedia'
4. Run through array of mounted media paths to find one containing name of targeted disc

Anyway, this is what I've came up with as a possible solution.  Anyone else have any other ideas/knowledge in this area in Cocoa?  Suggestions :)

EDIT:
I made this code below, but isn't working.  It creates an NSCFArray which contains NSCFStrings, which I read up and shouldn't be doing.

```
 NSArray *mountedItems = [[NSWorkspace sharedWorkspace] mountedRemovableMedia];

 int count = [mountedItems count];
 int i = 0;

    for (i = 0; i < count; i++) {
         //line is not printing.  contains NSCFArray and NSCFStrings
            [NSLog print:[[mountedItems objectAtIndex:i] stringValue]];
 }
```

Comment: Why wouldn't you expect mountedItems to be an array of strings?  And since when is NSLog a class?

Comment: Heh, yah.  Might be multiple problems with my code.  And I read somewhere that the programmer should never end up with 'NSCFStrings', and that they are to be used internally by Cocoa - and that the user should only be able to access and use NSStrings.

Comment: Got it working now. Updated the code down in my answer below.

Comment: Jeffrey Kern: I think you misread that, wherever it was. You should never use the name NSCFString in your code, nor expect that any given object will be an NSCFString as opposed to some other member of the NSString class cluster, nor try to avoid receiving an NSCFString. The existence of the NSCFString class is an implementation detail, meaning that it's part of how they implemented NSString—NSCFStrings *are* NSStrings. You need only to pretend that all but NSString and NSMutableString don't exist, and read “NSCFString” as “NSString” whenever the former name appears in the debugger.

Comment: Ah.  Yah I'm relatively new to Cocoa programming.  Thank you for the clarification.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, so I'm an idiot.

```
[[NSWorkspace sharedWorkspace] checkForRemovableMedia];
NSArray *mountedItems = [[NSWorkspace sharedWorkspace] mountedRemovableMedia];

NSUInteger count = [mountedItems count];
NSUInteger i = 0;
for (i = 0; i < count; i++) {
    NSString *tempString = [mountedItems objectAtIndex:i];
    NSLog(@"%@",tempString);
}
```

I was not only using NSLog wrong, but completely didn't even realize that perhaps calling 'stringValue' on a string is redundant.  And also what caused the code to break. :P

This works now; I also added 'checkForRemovableMedia' as an extra precaution.

Comment: “I also added 'checkForRemovableMedia' as an extra precaution.” No need; it currently does nothing and is deprecated since Snow Leopard. http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSWorkspace_Class/DeprecationAppendix/AppendixADeprecatedAPI.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSWorkspace/checkForRemovableMedia